# How to Use One Realm Object from another Realm Object?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have two realm Objects, one is Booking and Guest.below is the sample objects.

```
open class Booking: RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id:Int = 0
    var guest: Guest? = null
}
open class Guest: RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}
```

my requirement is based on the guest id, retrieve the booking.below is my sample query.

```
val booking = realm.where<Booking>().equalTo("guest.id", 1).findFirst()
```

but it returns the null object.how to achieve the above scenario in Kotlin android?

Comment: did you use `realm.where(Booking.class)`or an empty where?

Comment: @tamtom i updated my query

Comment: @Rajesh, is the "guest.id" parameter that you want to find the value?? and try to pass as `int` as 1 instead of `String`

Comment: @RakeshKumar i updated and above query is sample one.

Comment: @Rajesh, I asked you, is the "quest.id" parameter that you want to find the value accordingly?? Where is your Booking Class???

Comment: guest.id is the table column name

Comment: @RakeshKumar i didn't understand.

Comment: @Rajesh, before this, did you check the Realm has data that you inserted earlier?

Comment: data is available in realm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189175/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-rajesh).

Comment: Clearly, the `guest` is not actually set to the `booking`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how to set the guest to booking?

Comment: `booking.guest = guest`.